# Is it possible to Generate a Pdf Design by using Fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdf-generation, fpdf

[image]I want to Generate a Pdf in Php Using FDPF.  can we draw a table in fpdf. I want to Design a Table In the Image given Using FPDF.Is it Possible. I am new to fpdf Please help me. I want Above table design. Thanks in Advance

Comment: show us some code to point out what you already tried and what you want to achieve

Comment: FPDF has pretty good examples on their site... building this should be pretty easy, are you even going to try? Or just continue to ask others to build it for you?

Answer (score 1):

you should download an addon called PDF_MC_TABLE or copy it from here: http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/3/

```
$pdf = new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->Row(array("this\nis a test","with a multi\ncell"));
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: i think this is not possible by normal use of this extension. Maybe you can draw another 3-column table with S,M,L inside over the data-tables head. Something like colspan, rowspan is not supported.

Comment: that S, M and L are fetching from database.. for example if user add XL means it must come after L. can u get me what i am expecting

Comment: thats what i thought. but the Caption S M and L is static or isnt it. the only problem of your table is the header. You should draw it seperatly by using 2 tables one over the other. the first table should have 13 colums and a height of for example 50 beginning at Y=10. And the second table has 3 colums with a height of 25 also beginning at Y=10. Each of this second tables coulum has a width of 3 colums of the first table. The data itself is printed inside another 13 column table beginning at Y=60. Hope it is clear what i mean...

Comment: S,M and L is not Static it is dynamic

Comment: The content or the caption? however, it doesnt matter if you do like i explained

Comment: its like caption that must fetch from database table

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. It is not the correct design for what you are looking for, but it will helpful to you to create a table.

```
     require("fpdf.php");

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->SetTextColor(192,192,192);
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'Name:',1,0,'C',false,0);
$pdf->Cell(130,10,'Ali',1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'Subject:',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(130,10,'Maths',1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'Maximum Marks:',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(130,10,100,1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'Marks Obtained:',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(130,10,88,1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'Percentage:',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(130,10,88,1,1,'C');
$pdf->Output();
```